# getText() always return empty string from dynamically created Chip component?

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-chips

I'm trying to dynamically create some choice chip components based on an ArrayList of String from some computation and following are the code to create the chips and adding them to a ChipGroup created in layout XML file.

```
        if (mChipGroup.getChildCount() == 0 ){
            int i = 0;
            for (Classifier.Recognition res: results){
                Chip resultChip = new Chip(getDialog().getContext());
                ChipDrawable chipDrawable =
                        ChipDrawable.createFromAttributes(
                                getActivity(),
                                null,
                                0,
                                R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Chip_Choice);
                resultChip.setId(i++);
                resultChip.setChipDrawable(chipDrawable);
                resultChip.setText(res.getTitle());
                mChipGroup.addView(resultChip);
            }
        }
```

The Chips displayed correctly with the text but when I tried to call getText() on the chips, it always return empty String but not the text contained by the chips. I tested this by setting the OnCheckedChangeListener on the ChipGroup and making a Toast with the text (though it didn;'t work). When I tried to display only the checkedId it works.

```
        mChipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new ChipGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(ChipGroup group, int checkedId) {
                Chip chip = group.findViewById(checkedId);
                if(chip != null){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), chip.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

My current workaround is to have a variable holding the array results and use `ArrayList.get(selectedChipId.getTitle())`. but don't think it should be that way though

I also found that it is able to get text from Chips added in layout file but not run-time added Chips. Tried with both 1.1.0/alpha06 and 1.1.0/alpha07 release but am having no luck. Would like to have some advice if possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: can you get correct chips Id by clicking on them? also do you have a ChipGroup? take a look at this example: https://android--code.blogspot.com/2019/01/android-kotlin-create-chip.html

Comment: @payam hi yes I could get the correct chip id and have referred to multiple examples on getting the text but still having no luck. My current workaround is to have a variable holding the array results and use `ArrayList.get(selectedChipId.getTitle()).` but don't think it should be that way though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems like a bug as per answered in [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/394) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135180392). Current workaround is to use `((ChipDrawable) chip.getChipDrawable()).getText()` instead.

Comment: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/8c0f6f72c96d502cde11504f02cd5b9042fe25fd#diff-517b28ba515355e7ccfece81507a8cc1

the change is committed